# upload image from local computer to cloudinary server using php (yii2)

Tags: php, yii2

I'm using yii2 framework to make a website do upload to Cloudinary through its API.
but for some reason the API function that requires a path of the file to do the upload.

files in web folder can be uploaded but I don't want to make upload to my server and than send it to cloudinary server (too many actions), I want to make upload from my local host directly to cloudinary server

the upload code  from yii2 controller:

```
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new Galerias();

        // inicializar o cloudinary
        $config = Configuration::instance();
        $config->cloud->cloudName = 'cloudName';
        $config->cloud->apiKey = 'yayaiknow';
        $config->cloud->apiSecret = 'gogogodude';
        $config->url->secure = true;

        // esta a ser feito o upload
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $data2 = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
            if($model->validate()) {
                $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
                // maybe remove this if to get URL of image from callback
                if((new UploadApi())->upload($image)){
                    $data = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
                    $model->created_at = $data;
                    $model->updated_at = null;
                    if($model->save()){
                        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);

    }
```

code of the form:

```
<div class="galerias-form">
    <p>Imagem (tipo PNG-8) para: </p>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput()->label('Monitores "Dimensão recomendado: 1920x1080px"'); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'descricao')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'local')->radioList(array(0=>'Destaque',1=>'Fundo')); ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Guardar', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

</div>
```

And when I try to make the upload (boom) i get this error:

```
Cloudinary\Api\Exception\BadRequest
Unsupported source URL: a.jpg
```

I have tried to get the original relative (or absolute) path of the file, but with no success.

A solution that works is to upload the file to my website server, get there and send it to the Cloudinary server and finally remove that image from the website server. (too many steps)

I need help to make it simple, upload the file send it to Cloudinary and get the URL location on the callback and save it on the database.

links:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_and_video_upload

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/input-file-upload

Comment: To upload direct from the local machine you'd need to use JavaScript + Ajax to upload a file which the user selects. PHP cannot ever see the local machine directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the file path you are passing the `UploadedFiles` object which is unknown to the Cloudinary upload api.

You should pass the path via `$image->tempName` to the `(new UploadApi())->upload()` like below

```
(new UploadApi())->upload($image->tempName)
```

Also the method returns the response of file upload, a sample is below

```
Array
(
  [public_id] => c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0
  [version] => 1571218607
  [signature] => f8645b000be7d717599affc89a068157e4748276
  [width] => 864
  [height] => 576
  [format] => jpg
  [resource_type] => image
  [created_at] => 2017-06-23T13:59:18Z
  [bytes] => 120253
  [type] => upload
  [url] => http://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1571218607/c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0.jpg
  [secure_url] => https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/v1571218607/c87hg9xfxrd4itiim3t0.jpg
)
```

Or throws an exception on error, you should instead use try catch block.

```
try{
    (new UploadApi())->upload($image->tempName);
}catch(\Exception $e){
   Yii::$app->session->setflash('error',$e->getMessage());
}
```

Your complete action should look like

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Galerias();

    // inicializar o cloudinary
    $config = Configuration::instance();
    $config->cloud->cloudName = 'cloudName';
    $config->cloud->apiKey = 'yayaiknow';
    $config->cloud->apiSecret = 'gogogodude';
    $config->url->secure = true;

    // esta a ser feito o upload
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        $data2 = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
        if ($model->validate()) {
            $image = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image');
            // maybe remove this if to get URL of image from callback
            try {
                $response = (new UploadApi())->upload($image->tempName);
                $data = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');
                $model->created_at = $data;
                $model->updated_at = null;
                if ($model->save()) {
                    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', $e->getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);

}
```

Comment: that is it ! love u Reborn, that is it.

Comment: lol @Coyas you are welcome, please mark the answer as correct if it helped you.